# Swift: How do I sync local data in my iPhone with backend server when using Realm when reconnected to Internet?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am currently using Realm in our iOS swift app for local caching. When I delete a message while I am connected to the network it gets deleted without any issue. But, when I am not connected to the network and delete a message, the message gets deleted but, later when I am reconnected to the network the data sync happens between server to realm and the deleted object reappears.

How do I try having a reverse sync, i.e sync data from local realm data in iPhone to backend server to notify changes like this and delete them.

```
@IBAction func deleteNote(_ sender: UIButton) {

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "DELETE_NOTE_CONFIRM".localized, style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

let a = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

Alamofire.request(Router.deleteIncomingMessage(incomingID: self.RealmNotes.incomingID)).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (r) -> Void in
    })

 a.rootViewController.reController?.ViewController.deleteRealmMessage(message: self.RealmNotes)
}
}}}
```

DeleteRealmMessage function

```
func deleteRealmMessage(message: RealmIncomingMessage) {

      try! realm.write {
           realm.delete(message)
      }

      ReloadRealmTableView()
 }
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @Jan I have added the code. Please check. Apart from that, I am curious how can we make the reverse sync happen. I mean sync the local Realm DB with Backend server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage 2 flags "isDeleted" and "isSynced" locally for each record.

Now when you are deleted particular record from local and connected to internet then record will be deleted physically from local as well as back-end and it works properly.

If you are not connected to internet then you need to set these 2 flags. "isDeleted=1" and "isSynced=0". So that particular record will not shown locally as it is deleted. (not physically, but "isDeleted=1").

When app connects to internet then you need to check "isSynced" flag and which record's flags are "0" (isSynced=0), you need to pass those all records to server to update. And then after you can physically delete local records whose flag is "1". ("isDeleted=1").

Hope it helps to you!